# Redirecting back after image delete

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

May be is very newbiesh the question but I can't figured it out how this can be done. So I have page where I list thumbs of different image categories. 
Here is what is in index.php

```
<a href="single_cat.php?cat_id='.$row['cat_id'].'"><p>'.$row['cat_name'].'</p></a>
```

Then in single_cat.php I list all items from this `cat_id`. All item has button `Delete` which open page whit warning if is really want to delete this image. This is button delete

```
<a href="dellImage.php?image_id='.$row['image_id'].'" class="btn btn-default" role="button">
   Delete
</a>
```

So what I trying is to redirect back user from `dellImage.php` to `single_cat` after the image is deleted.

In dellImage.php

```
if (isset($_GET['image_id']))
{
    $image_id = $_GET['image_id'];
}
else
{
    die('<code>Error! Please try again.</code>');
}

if ( isset($_GET['image_id']) && isset($_POST['image_id']))  
{                   
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT image_path FROM images where image_id = :image_id"); 
    $stmt->bindParam(':image_id', $image_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();
    if ($result = $stmt->fetch()) 
    {                       
        unlink("" . $result[0]);
        if($stmt = $pdo->prepare("DELETE FROM images WHERE image_id = :image_id"))
        $stmt->bindParam(":image_id", $image_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();
    }                   
    Database::disconnect();
if (isset($_POST)) {
    $_SESSION['deleted'] = '<code><center>The image is deleted!</center></code>';
} else {
    $_SESSION['deleted'] = false;
}
    header('Location: index.php');         
}
```

So I want to redirect back to `single_cat?cat_id=...` from which category is deleted image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your second link, you should also add the value of your `cat_id` in your URL, like this:

```
<a href="dellImage.php?image_id='.$row["image_id"].'&cat_id='.$_GET["cat_id"].'" class="btn btn-default" role="button">
   Delete
</a>
```

And then, for your redirection:

```
header("LOCATION:singlecat.php?cat_id=".GET['cat_id'].");
```

I would also like to ask if your link is inside a `<?php ?>` or inside `<html></html>`

Because if it is inside a `<?php ?>`, your link should look like this:

```
echo "<a href='dellImage.php?image_id=".$row['image_id']."&cat_id=".$_GET['cat_id']."' class='btn btn-default' role='button'>
   Delete
</a>";
```

If it is outside the `<?php ?>`, it should instead look like this:

```
<a href="dellImage.php?image_id=<?php echo $row['image_id']; ?>&cat_id=<?php echo $_GET['cat_id']; ?>" class="btn btn-default" role="button">
   Delete
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there.. Add `cat_id` param to delete button `dellImage.php?image_id='.$row['image_id'].'&cat_id='.$_GET['cat_id'].'` and in delImage.php at the end call `header('Location: single_cat.php?cat_id='.$row['cat_id']); exit;`
You can check cat_id param exists, otherwise you can redirect user to index.php

Answer (score 1):

well you have to take the category id when you are selecting the image_path from image table by image id,then you will get the cat id.And,you can easily redirect back to your "single_cat?cat_id= ? " page.

Answer (score 0):

use this :

```
window.location = 'single_cat?cat_id=...';
```

Comment: why you didn't do this? please explain